# Cannot select a value in the dropdown that is not visible using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to select the following value on the yahoo registration page(https://edit.yahoo.com/registration): Country dropdown for selecting country codes.

Code used:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month"))).selectByVisibleText("July");
        driver.findElement(By.id("selected-country-code-2")).click();
                new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("country-code-rec"))).selectByVisibleText("Venezuela (+58)");
```

I keep getting the following error

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: can you say me on which line your getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I can see few flaws in your code.

For selecting the month,day,year here is the code, that worked, tested on Firefox driver.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testGoogle()  throws Exception
{
    driver.get("https://edit.yahoo.com/registration");

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
    WebElement day = driver.findElement(By.id("day"));
    WebElement year = driver.findElement(By.id("year"));

    Select monthDropDown = new Select(month);
    Select dayDropDown = new Select(day);
    Select yearDropDown = new Select(year);

    monthDropDown.selectByVisibleText("July");
    dayDropDown.selectByVisibleText("6");
    yearDropDown.selectByVisibleText("2012");

}
```

Note that the country code, that your trying to select is not an `select` html tag, instead an `div` tag. So you cant use `Select` class here, from Selenium.

You have to come with our own algorithm to handle this.